# R-studio crash after a getURL loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a loop of size 59 but R continues to crash, this is the loop:

```
n=length(webpage)
count=0
i=1

for(i in 1:n)

{

#get the URL
u <- webpage[i]

doc <- getURL(u)

#get the text from the body
html <- htmlTreeParse(doc, useInternal = TRUE)
txt <- xpathApply(html, "//body//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)][not(ancestor::noscript)]", xmlValue)
txt<-toString(txt)
txt

#clean
txt<-(str_replace_all(txt, "[\r\n\t,]" , ""))
txt<-tolower(txt)

search <- c("wi-fi","router","switch","adsl","wireless")

stri_count_fixed(txt, search)

count[i]<-sum(stri_count_fixed(txt, search))
}
count
```

I tried with 3 and worked but with 15 didn't

Comment: Does it crash on a particular webpage? In any event, your example is not reproducible so people are unlikely to be able to help you. Please give a [mcve].